# Webform module (or more basic Drupal 7 configuration) doesn't send e-mails to my adress

Tags: drupal

I customized my webform module (everything I know), but it doesn't send e-mails to my adress (I just receive massage "Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender" in my spam that someone tried to send me e-mail.) How to solve this problem? I think the problem is more basic than webform module level, because the same kind of spam message I received before, when I was trying to change my password and achieve activation link to my e-mail adress. Can someone help me?

Comment: I found what was wrong. Yahoo, and other e-mail providers introduce new level of protection. They changed DMARC policy, so the problem was in FROM e-mail field because Webform module is not prepared for that changes yet. I had to do something quickly, so I improvised, using simple text field instead of e-mail field for my FROM field for users e-mails.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I use the [SMTP Authentication Support](https://drupal.org/project/smtp) module to avoid spam filters.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Webform Reply To](https://drupal.org/project/webform_reply_to) module, and set the default site email address in Configuration > System > Site information to be an address with the same domain as the website, to avoid problems with DMARC.

The visitor's email address will then be used for the "Reply-to:" field, and the website's email address used for the "From:" field, so that DMARC tests always pass.